# bootstrap form controls- custome widths

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

If I include `<div class="input-group">` control seems shorter, if I remove this div then they are exapnding. I am just trying to understand what is happening by adding input-group and form-group classes to the form. Could someone explain ?

http://jsfiddle.net/dUG4f/3/

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                         <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Application Information</h3></div>
                         <div class="panel-body">

                                <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-6">
                                   <div class ="form-group">
                                        <label for="text" >Contract State</label>       
                                        <div class="input-group">    
                                            <select name="State" id="State" class="validate[required] form-control">
                                            <option value="">Choose a State</option>                    
                                            <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                                            <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                                            <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                                            </select>                                                       
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class ="form-group">
                                        <label for="text" >Application Number</label>       
                                         <div class="input-group">   
                                        <input  class="validate[required] text-input form-control" type="text" name="AppNumber" id="AppNumber" />                                           
                                        </div>   
                                    </div>                                      


                             </div> <!-- col-lg-6 col close -->
                            </div> <!-- row close -->
                         </div> <!--  End of panel Body -->     
                    </div><!--  End of panel  -->       
                </div> <!-- end col-xs-6 -->

            <div id ="panel2" class="col-xs-6"> 
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Initial Premium</h3></div>
                        <div class="panel-body">                                

                        </div>      
                </div>  
            </div>

    </div><!-- End of second row -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.input-group` class has the following rules:

```
.input-group {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

It's the `display: table;` rule thats responsible for shortening the `<select>` element, since a table's width is determined by how much content it has (by default). The content "Choose a State" of the first `<option>` becomes its width.

The [`.form-group`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) class lets an element span the width of its container:

> All textual `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>` elements with `.form-control` are set to `width: 100%;` by default.

Answer (score 1):

`input-group` is described here:

- http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

You need them to group a input element with an extension as described in the documentation. In your case, you might leave it out since it's only limit your elements width.

`form-group` is described here:

- http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

> Wrap labels and controls in .form-group for optimum spacing.