# Twitter Bootstrap form control(Option) how do i parse the data to php?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In Twitter bootstrap in option under form-control, how do i parse/assign text to php when submit?

Lets say i have 2 countries in a form 
if the field of submit is country do i do it like this?

```
  <label class="control-label" for="userid">Listing Country:</label>
              <div class="controls">
              <select name="country" class="form-control">
    <option >Country</option>
    <option  value="United States">United States</option>
    <option  value="Canada">Canada</option>

</select>
              </div>
```

Or do i have to assign id to each one of the options, then do if "#Canada" is click then text=

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do here?  Why do your `<option>` tags have names?  Shouldn't the `name` be on the `<select>` tag?  You just read the values from `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Comment: The class goes on the select tag right? and the options goes onto the option tags, thats what i read from some tutorials. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275556/bootstrap-form-controls-custome-widths like in this example

Comment: The `name` goes on the [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select).  [`<option>`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) are the children.  `<option>`s have a `value`.  When you submit the form, the "value" of the `<select>` is whichever `<option>` is chosen (its `value` attribute is used).  I don't see `class`es use anywhere in your example.  What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I am just trying to understand how this option part work, as i have no clue at the moment of how i submit the "value", i edited the code above

Comment: i think i got it now tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably want some JavaScript that listens for when an `<option>` is selected from the `<select>`. From there, you could send the user to a new URL, or maybe make an AJAX post to a PHP endpoint.

In JavaScript with jQuery, something like this:

```
$("select[name='country']").on('change', function () {
    var selected = $(this).val();  # Would be something like 'United States'
    # Do something here
});
```